# How to insert data in table using the data type double

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever I tried to save my table using double data type this error appears please help I'm a newbie.

[image]

Comment: CREATE TABLE TRY (id int(10), Pno int(2), Hours DOUBLE(40,0)); like that.

Answer (score 0):

So your answer depends upon how you want to add *double* value in MYSQL.

1. If you want to query MYSQL through SQL then you should do the query using decimal value in your query instead of a comma.
   a query should be like this...

> INSERT INTO `comment` ( `no_of_comments` , `newField` ) VALUES (12,23.5)

Here *newField* is the double type and this query works fine.

2. And if you want to insert the default Decimal value in MYSQL database using *PHPMYADMIN* portal then you should add *double* value using the **comma** for decimal as...

[image]

Don't forget that you add **comma** just for defining the *length* of the decimal part, You add value in a proper *double* format for defining the value of the field.

Answer (score -1):

There might have issue in Table Structure.

You have to  Set `Double` Datatype with Length,Values Format.

[image]